# SQL query using data from different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to create a query in SQL Developer.
There is Table1. Data in Table1 is as following:
Ex.1

```
ID_Number       Time
12345           1
12345           2
12345           3
12345           4
12345           5
67890           1
67890           2
67890           3
etc.
```

This Table1 is connected to Table2 with this ID_Number and the Code_Number I need is in this Table2.

There is one BUT. For example in Table1 there are ID_numbers which has Time column as here in this example from 1-5. Then different ID_numbers and also from 1-5. Then there are some ID_numbers which has only for example 2, 4, 5 in Times column as below.
Ex.2

```
 ID_Number       Time
    54321           2
    54321           4
    54321           5
```

I need to create a query that takes out all the Code_Numbers from Table2 (which is connected to Table1 via ID_number), but only those which doesn't have all those ID_numbers from 1-5 (Ex.1).

Is there any way to make this query possible? If I know that there is certain amount of them. For example 5, so maybe I could cound them with inner select and if there are lesst than 5 for example, then it will return these Code_Numbers for me?

Comment: How are ID_Number and Code_Number in table2 related? Is one of the fields unique? Maybe even both? Or only the combination of the two?

Comment: In case it is possible for a Code_Number to be present twice in table2, with two different ID_Numbers, and one ID has all 5 times, but the other has less: Do you want the code number to appear or not?

Comment: This should be solvable with rather basic SQL supported by about every DBMS, but anyway: when asking SQL questions you should always tag your DBMS, because SQL is only the language used, but its dialects differ.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. I am using Oracle if you meant that?

ID_Number and Code_Number in Table2 are related basically by themselves. ID_Number has same row with Code_Number. ID_Number is just value what is used to connect ex. Table1 with Table2. They are both unique. There's only one row in Table 2 for ID_Number and for Code_Number

It would be best if the Code_Number would appear just once.

Basically for example one ID_Number has less than 5 in Times column in Table 1, but it still has more than 1 row maybe. So it would be nice if it would return just one Code_Number from Table2.

Comment: I've edited my answer according to what I understand from your comments. I know, table and column names are just examples, but it would have been good to use better names, though. `ID_Number` would much better be called `ID_Table2` for instance, as it helps understand the relation between the tables. And `time` is a strange name for a column not containing a time but a number.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I gather from your comments and from guessing:

- Code_Number in table2 is unique.
- ID_Number in table2 is unique.
- ID_Number in table1 is the ID of table2 and of course not unique in table1.
- The combination ID_Number + Time in table 1 is unique.

So your data model could be more or less thus:

- table2: code_number, code_name, ... Primary Key = code_number
- table1: code_number, time, ... Primary Key = code_number + time

But you went for an ID concept, so you get:

- table2: id_number, code_number, code_name, ... Primary Key = id_number, additional unique constraint on code_number
- table1: id_number, time, ... Primary Key (or at least a unique constraint) = id_number + time

With better names for table and columns:

- codes: id_code, code_number, code_name, ... PK = id_code, Unique Index on code_number
- code_times : id_code_time, id_code, time_number, ... PK = id_code_time, Unique Index on id_code + time_number

Yes? Then you would select from codes table, but exclude records for which all requested time numbers exist in the code_times table. To find the id_number that have all time numbers, group by id_number and count the distinct time numbers. Then use the found IDs to access table2.

```
select code_number
from table2
where id_number not in
(
  select id_number
  from table1
  where time in (1,2,3,4,5)
  group by id_number 
  having count(*) = 5
);
```

If a code_number / time pair can occur more than once in table1, then replace `count(*)` with `count(distinct time)`.

Comment: Hi, I've edited my answer according to what I gather from your last comment in which you try to answer my questions.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining me.
I till try to explain my thoughts a bit better next time.

I actually figured it out that day as well with something like that:

SELECT T2.CODENUMBER
FROM TABLE2 T2, TABLE1 T1
WHERE T2.ID_NUMBER=T1.ID_NUMBER 
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1 T1 WHERE T1.ID_NUMBER = T2.ID_NUMBER) < 5;

But anyway. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Your solution wouldn't find IDs where exist times 1, 2, 3, 4, and 6, for instance, because in spite of the missing 5 you don't get a count < 5.

Comment: And you shouldn't use implicit comma-separated joins which were replaced by explicit join syntax more than twenty years ago. Use `FROM TABLE2 T2 JOIN TABLE1 T1 ON ...` instead. But why do you join the tables at all? The only thing this does is that you don't get the IDs that have no time entry at all in table1. So you even get a wrong result (i.e.  records missing) because of the unnecessary join.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a join.

It would look something like:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM t1
RIGHT OUTER JOIN t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t1.ID IS NULL
```

a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` tells SQL to preserve the rows that don't match on the RIGHT hand table, by putting a NULL in the data from the left hand table.

We then filter where the left table is NULL, so we get the results that don't exist in the left table.

Updated SQL based on the comment:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM t1
RIGHT OUTER JOIN t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID 
    AND t1.Time = t2.Time
WHERE t1.ID IS NULL
```

Also, note that the SQL syntax might change depending on what version you're using.

Comment: Ok, Then I get the ones from Table2 that are basically not connected via ContractID to Table1? Am I right?

But how can I get these values, which are connected from Table2 to Table1, but has less than 5 values in Times column? Difference between Ex1 and Ex2.

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand the question, but if I get it correctly, then all we need to do is modify the join, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Basically I need all the values from Table2 which has less than 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 values in Table1 Times column. For example, if some ID_Number in Table1 has values like 2, 3, 4- then I need it. If Some ID_NUMBER has values like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5- I don't need it.

Comment: Ahh, I see - that is a bit more complicated. Let me think :)

Comment: Note that Time column is not in Table2. Table1 and Table2 are only connected with ID_Number. Would it be possible like that? I have no idea, how to write it, but: IF some ID_Number has less than 5 Time values in Table1, then return value from Table2. I mean, would it be possible to use Count(*) here?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this comparing `count`s from both the tables.

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c9349/2)

```
select t2.id 
from t2 
group by t2.id 
having count(*) < (select count(*) from t1  where t1.id = t2.id group by t1.id)
```